# Do direct sums of vector spaces induce direct sums on the space of forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, direct-sum

Assume $\mathcal U$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, and $\mathcal V$ and $\mathcal W$ are subspaces of $\mathcal U$ such that $\mathcal V\oplus \mathcal W= \mathcal U$. Let us set $\operatorname{dim} \mathcal V=q$, and therefore $\operatorname{dim} \mathcal W=n-q$.

I was wondering if the decomposition $\mathcal U=\mathcal V\oplus \mathcal W$ naturally induces a similar decomposition on the space of $k$-forms over $\mathcal U$. Maybe considering $k$-forms with some kind of vanishing property over the subspaces $\mathcal V$ and $\mathcal W$... but I am clueless.

Thanks!

Comment: $\bigwedge^k(\mathcal{V} \oplus \mathcal{W}) \cong \bigoplus_{i+j=k} \bigwedge^i\mathcal{V} \otimes \bigwedge^j\mathcal{W}$.

Comment: @JakeLevinson thanks for the comment. Anything in terms of $\bigwedge^k \mathcal V$ and $\bigwedge^k \mathcal W$? Or some subspace of $\bigwedge^k \mathcal U$ satisfying some other property? I was interested in its relation with $k$-forms such that $\iota_{U}\alpha=0$ or $\alpha(U_1,...,U_k)=0$ for $U$ in either $\mathcal V$ or $\mathcal W$...

Comment: Also, isn't that tensor product in the r.h.s. a wedge product? Thanks!

Comment: It is standard to write the $\otimes$, with the understanding that you take the image of the tensor product in $\Lambda^k$, but you're right. I don't understand your comment: You have $U$ and then you have $U_1,\dots,U_k$. If you're saying that $\iota_U\alpha = 0$ whenever $U$ is a vector in either $\mathcal V$ or $\mathcal W$, then $\alpha = 0$ by multilinearity. If you're saying that the expression vanishes when *all* $k$ vectors belong to $\mathcal V$ or to $\mathcal W$, then you're saying that the terms $i=k, j=0$ and $i=0, j=k$ in Jake's sum are absent.

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry for the late answer. Say $\mathcal A_{\mathcal V}$ is the set of $k$-forms $\alpha$ such that $\iota_U \alpha=0$ for any $U\in\mathcal V$, and same thing for $\mathcal A_{\mathcal W}$. Say also that $\mathcal B_{\mathcal V}$ is the set of $k$-forms $\alpha$ such that $ \alpha(U_1,...,U_k)=0$ when all $U_1,...,U_k$ are in $\mathcal V$, and same thing for $\mathcal B_{\mathcal W}$. Is it possible to obtain a decomposition of $\bigwedge^k\mathcal U$ that involves any of $\mathcal A_{\mathcal V}$, $\mathcal A_{\mathcal W}$, $\mathcal B_{\mathcal V}$ or $\mathcal B_{\mathcal W}$?

Comment: So $\mathcal A_{\mathcal V} = \bigwedge^k\mathcal W$ (the $i=0, j=k$ term in Jake's decomposition) and—perhaps surprisingly—$\mathcal B_{\mathcal V} = \mathcal A_{\mathcal V}$.

Comment: Yes that is surprising! What if you take a 4-dim $\mathcal U$ and a 2-dim subspace $\mathcal V$ spanned by $e_3$ and $e_4$? Then the 2-form $\alpha=\theta^1\wedge\theta^3$ (the $\theta$'s are dual to the $e$'s) vanishes on $\mathcal V$ in the $\mathcal B$-sense but not in the $\mathcal A$-sense, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: @TedShifrin In the previous $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ is a basis for $\mathcal U$, and $\theta^i(e_j)=\delta^i_j$ for $i,j=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: Sadly, no. $\iota_{e_4}\alpha = 0$, but $\iota_{e_3}\alpha = -\theta^1\ne 0$. So this form is not in $\mathcal A_\mathcal V$.